# Invalid regular expression on google analytics batchGet

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, re2

I am filtering with regex but getting this error

```
> Error: Invalid regular expression: '^(?!Minoristas autorizados|How To
> Buy|Home of your local|Buy a|Distribuidores autorizados)$'. Regular
> expressions should follow RE2 syntax.
```

Comment: I don't think negative lookaheads are supported by RE2. By the way, your regex cannot validate or capture anything else than an empty string, because you have just a lookahead between the start `^` and end `$` of your regex. What is the regex supposed to achieve?

Comment: Regex is for ,it should not start with given words like "How to " , this regex is working fine on JS @Kaddath

Comment: Google Analytics != JavaScript   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Comment: I confirm that [negative lookaheads are not supported in RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). By the way, i tested your regex and it seems to do as i said: [see here](https://regex101.com/r/5ZbeEg/1) (the /m modifier is here to test each line as a separate test)

Comment: yes @Kaddath "/^(?:Minoristas autorizados|How To Buy|Home of your local|Buy a|Distribuidores autorizados)/"; is working onow but doesnt gave output

Comment: Is it possible for you to do your check the other way? Without negative lookaheads, it's much easier to test if the string "begins by the words .." than to test if "doesn't start by the words .."

Comment: @Kaddath google api "not":"true", save me here :)